# IE 10 Zooms whole page after position: absolute;

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building responsive web on bootstrap and everything is finished.
I wanted to hide overflow at mobiles and tablets, so I've added next code, which worked just as I wanted:

```css
#imgContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 588px;
  right: 0;
}
```

But, suddenly, IE 10, if width goes smaller than ~398px ZOOMs all elements on the page!
I googled `zoom: 1;` but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: huh!! weird bug! could you provide a jsfiddle? easier to test!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/JtSDU/
Problem is visible, if I save/open html/css in IE 10.0.9200.16653.
In fiddle it's uncought.